# teasing apart integer value from array in sqlite3

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, type-conversion

I am running ruby 2.3 (for sqlite3 compability reasons).  The code below is the minimal snippets to produce a coherent question.

I have the following line in a method:

```
def pull_value(id_item_hash)
     ...
            ...
            pull = db.execute2 "Select Level from sometable where Id = :id OR Item = :item" ,id_item_hash[:id], id_item_hash[:item]
            @pull=Integer(pull) #@pull=Integer(pull[1]) DOESN'T solve the problem
            ...
     ...
end
```

However `@pull` returns an `Array` which leads to a `TypeError` in the line below:

```
#here
pulled = x.pull_value(id_item_hash)

#so these lines never run
print "subtract how much?: "; subtracting = Integer(gets.chomp)
new_value = pulled - subtracting
```

My question: **How can I tease away the first found value in column `Label` so my variable `pull` can hold this value, alone, as an integer?**

Comment: The [execute2](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3%2FDatabase:execute2) method returns the selected rows, plus a row for the names of the columns. `pull[1]` should give you the first row returned by the SQL query. `pull[1][0]` I think will give you the value you are looking for.

Comment: @Richard it appears that did the trick.  May I ask why `pull[1][0]` works as opposed to: `pull[1][2]'   Level is actually column 3 (cardinal 2)?  PS: perhaps throw this in as answer so I can accept?

Comment: Since you are selecting only the 'Level' column, it will be the 1st (zero index) item.

Comment: @Richard still odd b/c when I created table (ie `"create table x(Col, ..., LastCol)"` ) `Level` is `Col[2]`

Comment: This is the difference between saying `SELECT * FROM table` and `SELECT column_name FROM table`. In the first statement, you're saying, "Give me all the columns." In the second statement, you're saying, "Only give me ONE column."

Comment: IOW: `SELECT` can reorder columns temporarily. now I know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
id = id_item_hash[:id]
item = id_item_hash[:item]
pull = db.execute2("Select Level from sometable where Id = :id OR Item = :item")

# puts pull[1][0]
@pull = pull[1][0]
```